# Column text moves to new row whenever I add a space to the text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've just learnt about bootstrap and its grid system. I'll try to explain my problem using pictures. This is what I'm trying to achieve :

[image]

However, whenever I use caps the space moves the time into a new row :

[image]

The code I use :

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:grey; height:44px;">
      <style> p{
        margin-top:10px;
        color:white;
        display:inline-block;
      }
      </style>
      <div class="row">

          <p class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">Welcome</p>
          <p class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-10>"><span 
       id="datetime"></span></p>

<script>
var dt = new Date();
var show=dt.getMinutes();
if(show<10)show="0"+show;
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML ="ATHENS "+ dt.getHours() + 
    ":" + show;
</script>


      </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:grey; height:44px;">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="col-4 col-md-3 col-lg-1">Welcome</p>
        <p class="col-8 col-md-9 col-lg-11"><span id="datetime"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should solve your issue. You may want to play about more with the bootstrap column sizes to get it exactly how you like. If you don't want it to wrap you can also use `white-space: no-wrap` on your `<p>` tag.

[Learn about the Bootstrap Grid System](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

[CodePen Solution Link](https://codepen.io/Kxrl/pen/QPzbmP)